# Yii2: Prevent empty string in attribute of ActiverRecord

Tags: mysql, validation, activerecord, model, yii2

What's the best way to prevent that an empty string gets inserted into a field of an MySQL's InnoDB table? Allowed values are strings with more than zero characters or NULL.

I'm asking that because ActiveRecord model objects often get [loaded](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#load()-detail) with view's form data which don't know and thus don't send NULL values. In such a case I'd prefer that a NULL gets stored instead of the empty string.

Should I define a rule? Should I implement a setter? Use a trigger?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should simply use the [`default`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#default) validator, add this rule to your model :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       // ...
       ['attribute', 'default', 'value' => null],
       // ...
    ];
}
```

Comment: I think there isn't more to say.

Comment: Wonder if there is also a way to make it automatically trim values... That actually be done already at the stage of receiving the POST values from the form...